# Tkinter Form and DB Insertion

Tags: python, forms, tkinter

Hi I am trying to create a db for a golf game I play with my son and am having some issues.

I keep getting the following error when trying to insert data into my db:

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as TK
from tkinter import *
import pyodbc

golfers=Tk()
golfers.title("Golfers")
golfers.geometry('500x500')


#Databases

#Create a Database or Connect to one
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-SCL1250\SQLEXPRESS01;'
                      'Database=tgt;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
#Create Cursor 
c=conn.cursor()

# c.execute("""CREATE TABLE tours(
#     tour_code varchar NOT NULL,
#     description varchar (255),
#     PRIMARY KEY (tour_code))
# """)

# c.execute("""CREATE TABLE golfers ( 
#     golfer_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
#     last_name varchar (255),
#   first_name varchar (255),
#   tour_code varchar FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tours(tour_code)
#   PRIMARY KEY (golfer_id))
# """)

def submit():
    #Create a Database or Connect to one
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-SCL1250\SQLEXPRESS01;'
                      'Database=tgt;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    
    #Create Cursor 
    c=conn.cursor()
    
    #Insert into table
    c.execute('INSERT INTO golfers VALUES(:golfer_id, :last_name, :first_name, :tour_code)',
            {
                'golfer_id': golfer_id.get(),
                'last_name': last_name.get(),
                'first_name': first_name.get(),
                'tour_code': tour_code.get()
            })
    #Commit Changes
    conn.commit()
    #Close Connection
    conn.close()
    
    #clear the text boxes
    golfer_id.delete(0,END)
    last_name.delete(0, END)
    first_name.delete(0, END)
    tour_code.delete(0,END)

#Create Text Boxes
golfer_id = Entry(golfers, width=30)
golfer_id.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)
last_name = Entry(golfers, width=30)
last_name.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20)
first_name = Entry(golfers, width=30)
first_name.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20)
tour_code = Entry(golfers, width=30)
tour_code.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20)

#Create Text Box Labels
golfer_id_label = Label(golfers, text="Golfer ID")
golfer_id_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
last_name_label = Label(golfers, text="Last Name")
last_name_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
first_name_label = Label(golfers, text="First Name")
first_name_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
tour_code_label = Label(golfers, text="Tour Code")
tour_code_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Create Submit Button
submit_btn = Button(golfers, text="Add Record", command=submit)
submit_btn.grid(row=6, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=100)

#Commit Changes
conn.commit()
#Close Connection
conn.close()

golfers.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `conn.commit()` and `conn.close()` at the end just before the `golfers.mainloop()`? I don't know much about SQL but I don't think it should be there. Try removing it and look at the results

Comment: Thanks.   I still got the error after I commented out the commit and close

Comment: Wait why do you have `conn.close()` inside the `submit` function? Do you intend to only call it once?

Comment: No, but I want to close it every time after I close it.

Comment: If you move the `conn.close()` after the `golfers.mainloop()`, it should run only once after the window is closed. If you close it before that, it might no longer respond to your commits.

Comment: I finally got it.  There were several issues.  I had to enter some values in the Tours table before I could create a "Golfers" form because of the tour_id field and the the NOT NULL constraint.  The initial issue though was that I had the id field as an auto number field so I couldn't have it on the form.